# Imagemagick: non-conforming drawing primitive definition `path'

Tags: svg, imagemagick

SVG in question (I cleaned out anything that wasn't related to the issue):

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 330 360">

  <defs>
    <path id="SVGID_1_" d="M166.3,7.4c-1.2,0-2.4,0-3.6,0c-10.4,0.2-20.9,1.3-26.9,3.8c-31.3,15.1-36.7,36.2-35.4,65.6"/>
  </defs>

  <clipPath id="SVGID_2_">
    <use xlink:href="#SVGID_1_"/>
  </clipPath>

  <path
    clip-path="url(#SVGID_2_)"
    d="M166.7 1.5S129-4.3 112.9 3.8c-7.3 3.7-12 11.7-15.5 19.1-5.2 11.2-6.8 36.4-6.8 36.4l15.9 11.4c.2-8.2 6.9-17.4 10.5-25.1 3.9-8.2 1.1-6.7 3.6-8.2 15.4-5.9 30.5-1 46 0 16.5 1.1 33.4-6.4 46 0 2.6 1.5 1.6-.6 3.6 8.2 1.6 6.8 12 18.8 10.5 25.1l15.9-11.4s-1.6-25.2-6.8-36.4c-3.4-7.4-8.2-15.4-15.5-19.1-15.9-8.1-53.6-2.3-53.6-2.3z"/>

</svg>
```

When I run this file through Imagemagick 7.0.7-22 Q16 x86_64 using identify:

```
magick identify -verbose clipPath.svg
```

The output ends with this:

```
identify: non-conforming drawing primitive definition `path' @ error/draw.c/DrawImage/3284.
```

I've narrowed down the issue to line 12:

```
clip-path="url(#SVGID_2_)"
```

Cleaning up the SVG isn't really an option because users are going to be able to upload their own SVGs. So the question is:

A) Why is this happening?

B) Is there anything that can be done to Imagemagick that can fix this?

Comment: magick identify -verbose clipPath.svg works OK for me without an error/warning Version 7.0.5-5 on Windows 10

Comment: magick identify -verbose on your svg file works fine for me on Mac OSX Sierra and IM 7.0.7.22

Comment: It could be the SVG delegate that you are using with ImageMagick. It could be the IM internal MSVG (not so good), the RSVG delegate library (better) or Inkscape (probably the best). Which are you using? Or perhaps an older version of RSVG or Inkscape. My test just above that worked fine was using librsvg @2.40.18_0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is this happening?

As pointed out in the comments, the internal encoder/decoder is converting the SVG to MVG. The `use xlink:href="#SVGID_1_"` deferment (or would it be called redirect?) is not understood; and so, omitted. If you run the following...

```
convert clipPath.svg mvg:-
```

Something like the following would be outputted (whitespace indent added).

```
push graphic-context
  viewbox 0 0 330 360
  affine 1 0 0 1 0 0
  push defs
    push graphic-context
      path 'M166.3,7.4c-1.2,0-2.4,0-3.6,0c-10.4,0.2-20.9,1.3-26.9,3.8c-31.3,15.1-36.7,36.2-35.4,65.6'
    pop graphic-context
  pop defs
  push clip-path 'SVGID_2_'
  pop clip-path
  push graphic-context
    clip-path 'url(#SVGID_2_)'
    path 'M166.7 1.5S129-4.3 112.9 3.8c-7.3 3.7-12 11.7-15.5 19.1-5.2 11.2-6.8 36.4-6.8 36.4l15.9 11.4c.2-8.2 6.9-17.4 10.5-25.1 3.9-8.2 1.1-6.7 3.6-8.2 15.4-5.9 30.5-1 46 0 16.5 1.1 33.4-6.4 46 0 2.6 1.5 1.6-.6 3.6 8.2 1.6 6.8 12 18.8 10.5 25.1l15.9-11.4s-1.6-25.2-6.8-36.4c-3.4-7.4-8.2-15.4-15.5-19.1-15.9-8.1-53.6-2.3-53.6-2.3z'
  pop graphic-context
pop graphic-context
```

Notice that clip-path "SVGID_2_" has no content (nothing between push & pop stack), and that `defs` -> `graphic-context` is not identifed as a clip-path.

If you rewrite the MVG, it should work as expected.

```
push graphic-context
  viewbox 0 0 330 360
  affine 1 0 0 1 0 0
  push defs
    push clip-path 'SVGID_2_'
      push graphic-context
        path 'M166.3,7.4c-1.2,0-2.4,0-3.6,0c-10.4,0.2-20.9,1.3-26.9,3.8c-31.3,15.1-36.7,36.2-35.4,65.6'
      pop graphic-context
    pop clip-path
  pop defs

  push graphic-context
    clip-path 'url(#SVGID_2_)'
    path 'M166.7 1.5S129-4.3 112.9 3.8c-7.3 3.7-12 11.7-15.5 19.1-5.2 11.2-6.8 36.4-6.8 36.4l15.9 11.4c.2-8.2 6.9-17.4 10.5-25.1 3.9-8.2 1.1-6.7 3.6-8.2 15.4-5.9 30.5-1 46 0 16.5 1.1 33.4-6.4 46 0 2.6 1.5 1.6-.6 3.6 8.2 1.6 6.8 12 18.8 10.5 25.1l15.9-11.4s-1.6-25.2-6.8-36.4c-3.4-7.4-8.2-15.4-15.5-19.1-15.9-8.1-53.6-2.3-53.6-2.3z'
  pop graphic-context
pop graphic-context
```

> Is there anything that can be done to Imagemagick that can fix this?

Upgrading to ImageMagick 7 will offer *some* improvements, but as Mark correctly pointed out, you would gain so much more if you switch delegates to a SVG rendering engine that supports advanced features. Read the delegates.xml file shipped with ImageMagick, or [online](https://www.imagemagick.org/source/delegates.xml). Examples are given as inline-comments, and I wouldn't be surprised if you already have rsvg, or similar, installed on the system.

Answer (score 1):

If you run:

```
identify -list delegate
```

you will see that **ImageMagick** delegates dealing with `SVG` files to `rsvg` so make sure that is up-to-date.

Also check if any switches or options need to be added to deal with any specific, troublesome SVG elements, and these can be edited into your `delegates.xml` file.